# Could not install mysql-server using Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04

I am facing one issue. I am trying to install mysql-client mysql-server using below command.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client mysql-server libmysqlclient-dev
```

But here I am guessing that its installing properly. I am getting some errors also and those are given below.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libmysqlclient-dev is already the newest version.
mysql-client is already the newest version.
mysql-server is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gcc-4.8-base:i386 libasound2:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386 libasyncns0:i386
  libaudio2:i386 libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386
  libavahi-common3:i386 libcups2:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386
  libdrm-radeon1:i386 libelf1:i386 libexpat1:i386 libffi6:i386 libflac8:i386
  libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libgcrypt11:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
  libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libgnutls26:i386
  libgpg-error0:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386
  libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 libice6:i386 libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libjbig0:i386
  libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386 libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386
  libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 libllvm3.4:i386 libmysqlclient18:i386
  libogg0:i386 liborc-0.4-0:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libpciaccess0:i386
  libpulse0:i386 libqt4-dbus:i386 libqt4-declarative:i386 libqt4-network:i386
  libqt4-opengl:i386 libqt4-script:i386 libqt4-sql:i386 libqt4-sql-mysql:i386
  libqt4-xml:i386 libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 libqtcore4:i386 libqtdbus4:i386
  libqtgui4:i386 libqtwebkit4:i386 libsamplerate0:i386 libsm6:i386
  libsndfile1:i386 libspeexdsp1:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386
  libstdc++6:i386 libtasn1-6:i386 libtiff5:i386 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386
  libudev1:i386 libvorbis0a:i386 libvorbisenc2:i386 libwrap0:i386
  libx11-6:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386
  libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386
  libxcb1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386
  libxi6:i386 libxml2:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxshmfence1:i386 libxslt1.1:i386
  libxss1:i386 libxt6:i386 libxv1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 309 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.55-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here I need to install properly. Please help me.

Comment: You have another running check/update job. Just restart your computer.

Comment: After restarting system will it be ok

Comment: After restarting try to install it again.